# NetBeans made jar file won't launch by double clicking

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I know this problem has been discussed many times here. I am running on MAC with OSX 10.7.4  and NetBeans 7.2.1

I don't know if this is a new wrinkle or not, I'm a java newbie. In any event with my project selected in the projects window it shows the project:

`Idealizer -> Source Packages -> components-> AlsRun.java, GraphingData.java, Idealizer.java, jButtonListenerExample.java` .

AlsRun is the main class. I can run the code from within the IDE or by zipping up dist and moving it anywhere and typing: `java -jar "Idealizer.jar`" (from within "dist").

On the other discussions of this problem it seemed that MANIFEST.MF  was implicated. MANIFEST.MF appears correct:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.6.0_35-b10-428-11M3811 (Apple Inc.)
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: components.AlsRun
```

I believe that the following are two big hints.

**Big Hint 1** :

When I run the code from the command line the program takes over and the program name that appears on the screen is "components.AlsRun" .
When I attempt to launch it by double clicking (from the finder) a program is launched and the name that appears is "AlsRun". The program that is launched in the latter case does nothing and I can only kill it from within "force quit".

**Big Hint 2**:

After writing the last sentence I asked myself how to kill it from the command line. If I ran the program by double clicking and then ran `ps -A | grep java` it returned the following:

```
33383 ?? 0:00.84 /Library/Internet Plug-ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

- jar /Users/pearson/NetBeansProjects/Idealizer/dist/Idealizer.jar

When I run the program from the command line and then do `ps -A | grep java` it returns

```
33394 ttys001    0:01.46 /usr/bin/java -jar Idealizer.jar
```

It runs different versions of java depending on if I launch it by double clicking or the command line.

Apparently NetBeans thinks I am creating an "Applet" which is different than an Application?

I am at a loss here. The shortest version of the code that produces the error for me is:

```
package components; 
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class AlsRun {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);        

    };
}
```

Comment: Try the NetBeans RC1 7.3.

Comment: I'd say it's an issue of default handlers. If your system binds an Applet-Starter to *.jar it will be startet by that on double-click. Don't know where that can be configured in OSX, sorry.

Comment: I uninstalled NetBeans 7.2 and installed RC2 7.3 (couldn't find RC1).
It doesn't work from within the IDE.

Comment: I reinstalled 7.2 and it returned to the previous error.

Comment: I guess I found the code that is causing the problem.  Can double click if : private static Component aComponent; is commented out. Otherwise not.

public class AlsRun {
 //   private static Component aComponent;
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
      //        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
      //        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(aComponent);
        try {
            
             Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AlsRun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    };
}

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/javatomac3-137430.html

fixed the problem.